# Generate random number in range(java)

Tags: java

To generate a random number in a given range, we can write:

`Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min`.

I would like to know that is it equal to `Random().nextInt(max + 1) - min` OR not.

Comment: That is two random generators, how can they be equal?

Comment: the range of the first one is [min, max], the second, [-min, max - min]. So, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, just check the edge cases.
For `min = 5` and `max = 10`

`max - min + 1 = 6`, so `nextInt((max - min) + 1)` results in `minRand = 0` to `maxRand = 5`. Add min and you get a number between 5 and 10.

`max + 1 = 11`, so `nextInt(max + 1)` results in `minRand = 0` to `maxRand = 10`. Substract min and you get a number between -5 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, but it seems not easy to explain.

`(max - min) + 1` is the argument to `nexInt` method. It is the value from *0* to the total of elements in that range (from min to max) and then this range is moved to start at the minimum value.

In other words, `nextInt((max - min) + 1)` generates a random int from `0` to `max-min`. And adding `min` will result in a random integer from `min` to `max`.

The other expression is just wrong because from `0` to `max + 1` doesn't get the range of values you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know that is it equal to Random().nextInt(max + 1) - min OR not.

Definitely not the same. You can sub in 2 numbers for `max` and `min`. You will see their differences.

Let your min be `7` and max be `9`:

```
Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min
// Random().nextInt((9 - 7) + 1) + 7
// Random().nextInt(3) + 7
// Randomly generates (0, 1, 2) + 7
// Randomly generates (7, 8, 9)
```

Now swap 7 and 9 into the other code snippet:

```
Random().nextInt(9 + 1) - 7
// Random().nextInt(10) - 7
// Randomly generates (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) - 7
// Randomly generates (-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
```

One way for me to interpret how random.nextInt(val) works is by looking at the value of  `val`. Let say if the final evaluation of `val` is 5. There are 5 possibilities to be randomly generated starting from 0. `(i.e. 0,1,2,3,4)`